# How do you map Json structure having type identification inside the node

Tags: java, json, jackson

```js
{
  "task": {
    "vendorConnectorId": 9901,
    "operation": "query",
    "objectType": "",
    "attributes": {
      "q": "SELECT Name FROM Asset where AccountId = '00128000005O5uPAAS'"
    }
  },
  "httpStatusCode": 200,
  "resultSet": {
    "result": {
      "totalSize": 1,
      "records": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "type": "Asset",
            "url": "/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Asset/02i280000007BcpAAE"
          },
          "Name": "Flight To LA"
        }
      ],
      "done": true
    }
  },
  "messages": [],
  "startedTime": 1441969739375,
  "endTime": 1441969750317
}
```

I want to map `records` node via polymorphic de-serialization feature of Jackson but `type` information is nested inside the `record` node(attribute node).

Comment: Do you have any control over json structure?

Comment: No, I am consuming it only.